# How can this function return me some values?

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I am trying to build a python function that takes the user input and gives back some information stored inside neo4j database using cypher queries.

I have already tried out the below code but it is not working. Everytime someone types in VPS, I want to show him the recommendation of VPN which I have it as a service in my Neo4j database.

```py
def vps_vpn(result):
    if result == "VPS":
        # print (inside)
        query = '''
                      MATCH (prc:Price)<-[:COSTS]-(s:Service)-[:IS_PROVIDED]->(p:Provider)-[:OFFERS_PRODUCT]-> (pr:Product)
                      WITH rand() AS Random, s.service_name AS Service_Name, p.provider_name AS Provider_Name, pr.product_name AS Product_Name, prc.monthly AS Monthly, prc.currency AS Currency
                      WHERE Service_Name = "VPN" 
                      RETURN Service_Name, Provider_Name, Product_Name, Monthly, Currency
                      ORDER BY Random
                      LIMIT 5
                       '''
        return graph.run(query).data()
vps_vpn(result)
```

I am not getting any error but I am also not getting any recommendation for VPN when I type VPS. How can this be solved?

Comment: If you print out the result of the function, what is displayed? An empty array?

Comment: Your aren't doing anything with the returned result...

Comment: it will return only when `if` condition is true

Comment: instead of your last line, do this: `print(vps_vpn(result))`

Comment: Does your Cypher query actually return anything (e.g., if run from the neo4j browser)? Also, the query can be faster and simpler: `MATCH (prc:Price)<-[:COSTS]-(s:Service)-[:IS_PROVIDED]->(p:Provider)-[:OFFERS_PRODUCT]->(pr:Product)
WHERE s.service_name = "VPN"
RETURN
  s.service_name AS Service_Name,
  p.provider_name AS Provider_Name,
  pr.product_name AS Product_Name,
  prc.monthly AS Monthly,
  prc.currency AS Currency
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 5`

Comment: @cybersam Yes when I run the query to neo4j desktop returns me exactly what I need.

Comment: @SayandipDutta Thanks for the answer. I just wanted to know that graph.run(query).data() works as I want to.

Comment: Are you sure this function is getting the neo4j session passed into it?

Comment: @CJSullivan Yes already is working. I have a header to import graph from another file so this was not the problem. But I wanted to see what kind of data returns graph.run().data(). Thanks!!